# Efficient way to find first occurrence of key:value inside object

Tags: javascript

Below is the object in which I need to find at least one occurrence of `isSelected: true`.

```
 [
  {
    "isSelected": true,
    "child": [
      {
        "isSelected": true,
        "child": [
          {
            "isSelected": true,
            "child": [
              {
                "isSelected": true
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The above object can have *n* elements in it and each element can have *n* children and so on. For every element there will be an `isSelected` key with value "true/false".

I am trying to write a function in JavaScript that will return true if it finds at least one occurrence of `isSelected` key with true value.

Wrote below function using `JSON.stringify()` and search for string "isSelected:true" string in it

```
function hasIsSelected(data){
  return (JSON.stringify(data)).search('"isSelected":true') > -1 ? true: false
}
```

Not sure if `JSON.stringify()` will be efficient for large objects.

Trying to find solution in JavaScript without using third party library.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive algorithm to check the "isSelected" value and loop over all the children :

```
function hasIsSelected(data) {
    if (data.isSelected) {
        return true;
    }
    if (data.child) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.child.length; i++) {
            if (hasIsSelected(data.child[i])) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}


var json = [...]; // Your value
hasIsSelected(json[0]);
```

---

**EDIT :**
Ok let's make a very simple benchmark for the worst case :

```
function createTestData(depth) {
    var obj = { isSelected: depth === 0 };
    if (depth > 0) {
        obj.child = [createTestData(depth - 1)];
    }
    return obj;
}
var testData = [createTestData(1000)]; // Big object, the "true" value is in the deepest child.


function hasIsSelectedStrinfigy(data){
    return (JSON.stringify(data)).search('"isSelected":true') > -1;
}

function hasIsSelectedRec(data) {
    if (data.isSelected) {
        return true;
    }
    if (data.child) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.child.length; i++) {
            if (hasIsSelectedRec(data.child[i])) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Using NicolaeS's solution 
function hasIsSelectedRecTOC(data) {
    if (data.isSelected === true) {
        return true;
    }
    if (data.child instanceof Array) {
        // stops after the first valid element
        return data.child.some(hasIsSelectedRecTOC);
    }
    return false;
}


// Run tests
function runTest(fun) {
    var t0 = performance.now();
    fun(testData[0]);
    var t1 = performance.now();
    return t1 - t0;
}

console.log("Exec time using stringify : %o", runTest(hasIsSelectedStrinfigy));
console.log("Exec time using recursion : %o", runTest(hasIsSelectedRec));
console.log("Exec time using recursion with TOC : %o", runTest(hasIsSelectedRecTOC));
```

Results on my computer (change every time you run them but you get the idea) :

```
Exec time using stringify : 6.785000000000004
Exec time using recursion : 0.36999999999999034
Exec time using recursion with TOC : 0.37999999999999545
```

---

This was for the worst case. Now with the best case (the first isSelected is "true") :

```
function createTestData(depth) {
    var obj = { isSelected: true }; // isSelected is always true
    if (depth > 0) {
        obj.child = [createTestData(depth - 1)];
    }
    return obj;
}
var testData = [createTestData(1000)];
```

Results :

```
Exec time using stringify : 3.980000000000002
Exec time using recursion : 0.040000000000000924
Exec time using recursion with TOC : 0.02499999999999858
```

Comment: I think for worst case recursion will be slower will and takes up more of the stack memory?

Comment: Ok first I just fixed my function, it didn't return the correct result in some cases. No this way will be faster on big objects because you do not have to browse all "paths". When the first isSelected field is found with the value "true" it ends. If you use JSON.stringify the function will browse all the objets to turn it into a string, and then you will have to search in that big string.

Comment: I edited my answer to add a simple benchmark you can run to see the differences

Answer (score 1):

Building on the answer of @Junior - recursion is the fastest way to do it, but here is a more performant version using [tail call optimization](http://2ality.com/2015/06/tail-call-optimization.html):

```
function hasIsSelected(data) {
  if (data.isSelected === true) {
    return true;
  } else if (data.child instanceof Array) {
    return data.child.some(hasIsSelected); // stops after the first selected element
  } else return false;
}
```

Another important trick is to stop the loop as soon as a `true` is found.

Comment: Added your solution in my benchmark. Sometimes your solution using TOC is faster than mine, sometimes not. That's interesting !

Comment: Unfortunately, tail call optimization does not apply in this case, because of the "fan-out" involved. Tail call optmization refers to situations involving a single recursive call.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion will be the best way to do that:

```js
const deepSearch = (arr) => {
  return arr.some((v) => {
    if (v.isSelected === true) {
      return true;
    }
    if (Array.isArray(v.child) && v.child.length > 0) {
      return deepSearch(v.child);
    }
    return false;
  });
};
```

Here is [jsperf test](https://jsperf.com/jsonscan).

**Added**: `Array.isArray(X)` is ≈3.3 times faster than `X instanceof Array`. Here is [jsperf test confirming that](https://jsperf.com/array-isarray-vs-instanceof-array/5).